# Maximize already running window C#

Tags: c#

Below is the code which is working perfectly al-right.
If Application is already running, its Maximizing/Restoring the Application or showing it on Front .. Working Perfect, but now the problem is when window is in minimzed to System Tray.

```
 this.showInTaskbar = false;
 this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
```

It is not restoring the Application, What should i do ? to make it restore/maximize from System Tray also ?

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 1;


    public NewDesign(){
             InitializeComponent();

     if (!EnsureSingleInstance()){
                 System.Environment.Exit(0);
     }
   }

    static bool EnsureSingleInstance()
    {
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        var runningProcess = (from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                              where
                                process.Id != currentProcess.Id &&
                                process.ProcessName.Equals(
                                  currentProcess.ProcessName,
                                  StringComparison.Ordinal)
                              select process).FirstOrDefault();

        if (runningProcess != null)
        {
            ShowWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
            SetForegroundWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle);


            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The code is brittle, depending on MainWindowHandle is risky.  You made it worse by setting the ShowInTaskbar property to false, that causes the window to be recreated.  So don't do that, use this.Hide() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Your advice is good, but how should i show an hidden window then ? in the above method no argument working in showWindow(MainHandle, __________ );

Comment: If you can't figure it out then just don't use it.  Jeffrey gave you excellent advice, avoid reimplementing something that the framework already supports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to reference the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` runtime from your C# project, derive an application class from [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx) (you can do that even in C#), set `IsSingleInstance = true` on it, and handle the `StartupNextInstance` event.  Won't work under some circumstances, but works for the common cases.

A more idiomatic C# way to do it can be found in [this old chestnut](http://web.archive.org/web/20080506103924/http://www.flawlesscode.com/post/2008/02/Enforcing-single-instance-with-argument-passing.aspx) that fell beneath the sands of time and had to be excavated using the Wayback Machine: using a named pipe to talk to the already-running instance.  There's even some code you can use there.